# add a variable inside a wordpress array function

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a function that adds an admin panel area with a field who is being pulled as a variable.

The idea is to allow my client to decide which categories will be excluded from the search results.

I found this great code:

```
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'search_exc_cats' );
function search_exc_cats( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_admin )
        return $query;
    if( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in' , array(1,64) ); // Example multiple cats
    }
    return $query;
}
```

What works great and added my code that pulles the veriable above it:

```
$omr_tracking_code = get_option('omr_tracking_code');
```

but when I try to put the variable: `$omr_tracking_code` inside the "array", it doesn't work.

This is my full code what doesn't work:

```
    $omr_tracking_code = get_option('omr_tracking_code');
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'search_exc_cats' );
function search_exc_cats( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_admin )
        return $query;
    if( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in' , array($omr_tracking_code) ); // Example multiple cats
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: what is an example value of $omr_tracking_code?  you could use error_log($omr_tracking_code); and check your error log to check.  possibly it's already returning an array, so then you're doing an array of an array.

Comment: i am using this code: http://buildinternet.com/2010/01/create-custom-option-panels-with-wordpress-2-9/
it dose not use an array, i think. when i do "echo $omr_tracking_code" - it shows the values i want. but still it dosn't happen inside the array

Comment: So you've confirmed that the code works by putting in actual category ids such as array(1,64) - where 1 and 64 are actual ids?

Comment: yes. i confirm that... so what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on our comments discussion, it seems that you're getting back an option like:

```
"1, 64"
```

then you're trying:

```
array ("1, 64")
```

which won't work.

You need to be doing:

```
array("1", "64")
```

So try the code below first using option 1.  If that doesn't work, then option2 also converts the values into integers (which may or may not be necessary):

```
array(1, 64)
```

So try one of the two options:

```
function search_exc_cats( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_admin )
        return $query;
    if( $query->is_search ) {
        $option1 = explode(',', $omr_tracking_code);
        $option2 = array_map('intval', explode(',', $omr_tracking_code));
        $query->set( 'category__not_in' , $option1 );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: i tried both options, it doesn't work. but i think you miss understood me. this works: $query->set( 'category__not_in' , array(1,64) ); without the Quotation marks. when i do this: echo $omr_tracking_code;... i get :1,64 (also without a Quotation marks) so i know the variable is working

Comment: right, so the problem is that you are getting back a value of 1,64, but as a single string.  try "echo count($omr_tracking_code);" and you'll probably get 1.  then try "echo count(explode(',', $omr_tracking_code));" and you should get two.

Comment: my need is to have the values inside the excluded category filter..but all the scripts above didn't work